# Java code to import multiple Data csv files into PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, data-migration

I have huge multiple csv files, which has table data from Oracle DB. I need to automate the Data migration process using Java, to upload those csv files into Postgres DB.

Comment: JDBC executeUpdate with a COPY statement: https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/import-csv-file-into-posgresql-table/

Comment: HI Thank you. I've gone through the link provided. I have 100's of .csv files with many columns (Scenario:Columns's types, count, names are not known & csv file name is same as table name).  The command provided here are explicitly need to given in query window. I need this process to go in loop with the scenario mentioned.

Comment: This Process i need to build up in local currently by fetching all csv's. Later time, need to have this process on server.

Comment: **#1#** There is `Connection.getMetaData` and from the .csv files the file name and the column names. With that you should be able to generate prepared statements for ISNERTs, and even CSV parameter fill java commands. So one could do all oneself. **#2#** If the CSVs are not on the server, you can first test it locally in your own Progresql DB (open source!). You might afterwards use a gzipped dump. One problem with a massive DB imports consists of referential integrity constraints.